# How to check a particular date is in between two different dates?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working in mysql database, and I have a table called bookings in that two columns named `start_date` and `end_date` And I get a date value from my php script

Can anybody tell me how can I check that date is in between those `start_date` and `end_date`

I have tried this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_booking` WHERE '$date' between Start_date AND end_date");
```

Comment: What is wrong with your SQL? that is the correct syntax and it should work unless the value of $date is not a valid date.

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_booking WHERE date_column BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BETWEEN** assumes that you have some values and comparing column with them. I believe it should be something like: `WHERE Date(start_date) <= '$date' AND Date(end_date) >= '$date'`

PS: Not sure about PHP's var interpolation though. Added typecast from one of answers, that seems to be correct.

Comment: thank u.. your answer helped me to find solution..

Answer (score 0):

if you have column type `Date` then try

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_booking WHERE date_column between Start_date AND end_date");
```

if `Datetime` then

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_booking WHERE Date(date_column) between Start_date AND end_date");
```